# MacBook kernel panic error screen on boot

Tags: macbook-pro, error, kernel-panic

This MacBook had milk spilled on the keyboard a few months ago. It's continued to work, with a few of the letter keys no longer functioning, up until this point. Now, upon start up, the MacBook just displays an error screen and performs no other function.

The error message:

[image]

Is there any saving this MacBook from becoming an expensive paper weight??

Answer (score 1):

You should take the computer in to your local Apple Store or Apple Authorized reseller. It may be that the milk (or milk residues) finally dripped down enough to short out parts of the motherboard.

Don't try lying to them; fess up to the milk spill and maybe you'll get lucky. In any case, you're looking at what is likely to be an expensive repair (involving the motherboard, keyboard, and anything in between).